# Link pie chart to data tables in Pentaho User Console

Tags: pentaho, pie-chart

Can anyone help me in creating analysis report in Pentaho User Console?
I already create 1 pie chart & 2 table of list. What I need to do is I need to make it like this: In that pie chart, it show 2 record. Let me call it as Status A & Status B. When I click a slice named status A, it link to other page that show table of list that related to status A. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

try Dashboards.fireChange("your_param", theparamsvalue); in the pie's clickAction property.theparamsvalue could be this.getValue() to store the current selection;also in the pie's properties activate clickable, selectable and so on