# updating data table when clicking on pentaho pie chart slice

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

Any updates for the above question( [Link pie chart to data tables in Pentaho User Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869989/link-pie-chart-to-data-tables-in-pentaho-user-console) ). I have a question for the same.

I have already created 1 pie chart & a data table(lists the pie chart slice details) in pentaho report designer and successfully published on server(biserver-ce 5.0.1 stable).Now, I need to make it like this: In that pie chart, it show 2 record. Let me call it as Status A & Status B. When I click a slice named status A, it should update data table of list that related to status A.

Can anyone tell me how I can do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try Dashboards.fireChange("your_param", theparamsvalue); in the pie's clickAction property.theparamsvalue could be this.getValue() to store the current selection;also in the pie's properties activate clickable, selectable and so on